# Relation betwen a $p$ norm and dual norm

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, normed-spaces, dual-spaces

Consider
$$
A=\{y\in \mathbb{R}^{n}: \langle y,x \rangle\le \lVert x \rVert_p \quad \mbox{ for all }x\in \mathbb{R}^n \}
$$
and
$$
B=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}: \lVert x \rVert_{q}\le 1 \}
$$
where $p, q\in [1,\infty]$ such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. How can I prove that $A\subseteq B$. I have no idea how to start with this demonstration. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Holder's in someway can be useful I guess :(

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use the vector $x$ with $x_i = \operatorname{sign}(y_i) \, |y_i|^\alpha$ for some appropriate power $\alpha \in \mathbb R$.